# Podio API filtering by date range

Tags: api, podio

I'm trying to filter tasks by date range and I'm getting errors whatever I try. This is how my request looks like: http://api.podio.com/task?completed=true&created_on%5Bfrom%5D=2016-06-23&created_on%5Bto%5D=2016-06-28&limit=100&offset=0&sort_by=rank&sort_desc=false&space=4671314

Here I'm trying to filter by created_on and I'm suplying `{from: "2016-06-23", to: "2016-06-28"}` but it's always returning the same error - `invalid filter`. I'm trying to filter tasks that are created in the last 5 days here.

The tasks API reference can be found in [their API docs](https://developers.podio.com/doc/tasks/get-tasks-77949).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you please provide the error exception?

Answer (score 4):

Date ranges can be separated by `-`.

To display **"all my tasks created between 1st Jan 2014 and 1st Jan 2016"** :-

```
/task?created_on=2014-01-01-2016-01-01&responsible=0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Podio API get task filtering by date range use below :

/task/?created_on=2017-04-25-2017-05-01&offset=0&sort_by=rank&sort_desc=false&space=xxxxxxx